# Who was girl that regenerated at "Day of the moon" from doctor who

Tags: doctor-who, regeneration, river-song

So at the end of "Day of the moon" small girl regenerated, but I thought it was river song, but how small river song
could be there?

Comment: https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Sydney_Wade

Comment: Downvoted for a complete absence of research effort.

Comment: So, who was it? I search on Russian wiki, didn't find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's River Song, as explained later in the season during the episode "Let's Kill Hitler", as Mels starts to regenerate after being shot:

(Emphasis mine)

> DOCTOR: Back! Back! Back! Get back!
>
> MELS: **Last time I did this, I ended up a toddler in the middle of
> New York.**
>
> AMY: Okay, Doctor, explain what is happening, please.
>
> DOCTOR: Mels. Short for
>
> MELS: Melody.
>
> AMY: Yeah. I named my daughter after her.
>
> DOCTOR: You named your daughter after your daughter.
>
> ...
>
> RORY: But if she's Melody, that means that she's also
>
> MELS: Shut up, Dad. I'm focusing on a dress size.
>
> (And Mels transforms into...)
>
> **RIVER SONG**: Oh! Oh! Oh! Whoa! Right, let's see, then. Ooo, it's all going
> on down there, isn't it? The hair! Oh, the hair. It just doesn't stop,
> does it? Look at that. Everything changes. Oh, but I love it. I love
> it! I'm all sort of mature.